# How to specify IE to use 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Java for specific URLs or Applications? Would Java Deployment Rule Sets Work?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java, internet-explorer, 32-bit

For our current use case, it is required that we have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of java installed on Windows 7 64-bit client computers. The 32-bit version is required for Legacy applications and is set as the default for IE 11 64-bit. We have a java program pushed through a URL that needs to run using 64-bit Java instead of the Default 32-bit version.

Since IE is running in Enhanced Protected Mode, we have even tried enabling

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Isolation"="PMEM"
"Isolation64Bit"=dword:00000001
```

We still see the 32-bit java version of the program running in the logs. We have looked into Java Deployment Rule Sets but I have only seen ways to specify different java version numbers and not 32-bit or 64-bit of the same version number.

Is there something we could add to this as an example?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you using a 32-bit plugin with a 64-bit browser that does not make sense because that isn't possible.

Comment: If the browser is in enhanced protected mode, then by default unless otherwise specified but the above reg entries 32-bit tabs are opened within 64-bit IE.

Answer (score 0):

EPM runs in AppContainer 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2864914/enhanced-protected-mode-add-on-compatibility
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode

64 Bit EPM doesnt use App container. So if you have both EPM and 64bit EPM your frame and Tab process are 64 bit however your tab process is 64 bit appcontainer and your java add-on would not work until its EPm compatible.

So the ideal way is to disable EPM and then try to reproduce the issue.